# ConditionPathIsEncrypted not supported?

Tags: systemd, mount, luks, systemd-unit

I've created a unit file to mount the /srv partition automatically. It will check first if `/dev/mapper/srv` exists and then start it. I'd like to take it one step further and only let it be able to start if `/dev/mapper/srv` is a LUKS encrypted block device, with the `ConditionPathIsEncrypted` option. But I get the warning: `/etc/systemd/system/srv.mount:4: Unknown lvalue 'ConditionPathIsEncrypted' in section 'Unit'`

I tried giving it a boolean value, that also didn't work. Putting it in the `[Mount]` category also didn't solve it.

```
[Unit]
Description=srv mount
ConditionPathExists=/dev/mapper/srv
#ConditionPathIsEncrypted=/dev/mapper/srv

[Mount]
What=/dev/mapper/srv
Where=/srv
Type=ext4
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I didn't see that it was a very recent feature. My version is pre-246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConditionPathIsEncrypted=` only exists in versions v264-rc1 and newer.

If you want to look what conditions the version you are using supports, i would suggest you take a look at the 'systemd.unit' manpage.

```
man systemd.unit
```

There is a section with 'Conditions and Asserts' - the systemd version shipping with Ubuntu 20.04 for example is v245 and thus is missing the `ConditionPathIsEncrypted=` condition.